# visualsvn trac like on windows

Tags: svn, trac, visualsvn-server

We have been using TRAC with VisualSVN but it's become a pain to work with, alot of outdated python libraries etc.

Because all our servers are on Windows 2008 we use VisualSVN, now we need something like TRAC but more native W2k8 support. TRAC is a good package, we just need: ticketing with comments to SVN, milestones, components etc.

Comment: Are there any valid arguments against trac? Sorry for grabbing this question out from nowhere...

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to list options that came to my mind:

- You can install Trac to up-to-date VisualSVN Server versions via mod_wsgi Apache module and Python bindings that are now packaged with VisualSVN Server. This will require modifying `%VISUALSVN_SERVER%conf\httpd-custom.conf` file and is generally *not recommended*. As far as I understood from your question, you'd like to avoid this approach.
- You can install any other bug tracker like JIRA, Trac, Bugzilla, you name it to a dedicated web server instance. Don't connect the bug tracker to Subversion repositories, i.e. don't use it as a web interface (e.g. Trac can be used as a web interface for SVN repos). Instead of this, use [HTML5-powered web user interface of VisualSVN Server](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/svn-web-interface/) for repo browsing and setup post-commit hooks that should be packaged with the bug tracker. In such case you get a neat web interface for repository browsing with integrated authentication and authorization and a bug tracker that contains your tickets, milestones, components, whatever.